# In Access can you rs.findfirst using more than one set of criteria

Tags: sql-server, ms-access, vba

Is it possible to use more than one set of criteria when using recordset.findfirst in an Access / SQL Server combination.

My code works fine when FindFirst-ing  `"Ref='XYZ'"`, but as soon as I make it `"Ref='XYZ' AND CustDate=#12-31-2010#"` it freezes and I have to EndTask Access.

Is this common or have I made a simple mistake.  I have indexes on both `Ref` and `CustID`

My recordset code is:

```
dim rsImport as DAO.recordset, rsSQL as DAO.recordset
set rsimport=CurrentDB().OpenRecordset("SELECT * from tblImport",dbopenSnapshot)
 rsimport.movelast
 rsimport.movefirst
set rsSQL=CurrentDB().OpenRecordset("SELECT * from tblRecords",dbOpenDynaset, dbSeeChanges)
 rsSQL.movelast
 rssql.movefirst
do while rsimport.eof=false
   rssql.findfirst "[RefID]='" & rsimport!RefID & "' AND [RefDate]=#" & format(rsimport!CustDate,"m-d-yy") & "#"
   if rssql.nomatch=true then
       debug.print "NOT FOUND - Add..."
   else
       debug.print "FOUND - Update..."
   endif
   rsimport.movenext
loop
```

Comment: This is a continuation of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11397943/should-access-recordset-findfirst-have-performance-issues-with-dates, is it not?

Comment: It is quite common to have more than one criterion in a pure MS Access environment (MS Access + Jet/ACE) however, I suggest you use a WHERE statement, rather than find with SQL Server.

Comment: It is related yes, but as that question was focused on performance with dates, I thought it better to ask it seperately. I can't use WHERE, it's a repetitive task that requires to test for existance of a [REF] / [DATE] combination, if it exists, edit it, if it doesn't exist, add/insert it.

Comment: But it is only when adding a second criteria.  `REF='XYZ'` works fine, making it `REF='XYZ' AND CustID=345` makes it slow to nothing.  Alt-Pause does not always work, possibly because it's taking so long to process that `rs.findfirst` line.  Maybe if I left it for an hr, it would reach the break-point, but my lack of patience won't allow for that.  At this point, I'm putting in a local temporary table that matches the server one, will bring down all 5000 records, merge them with the import table, then push them back up to the server.

Comment: If anyone has sucesfully done rs.findfirst in Access on a SQL Server source, please let me know.

Comment: Yes. On a small SQL Server table linked to MS Access I can easily use FindFirst with 2 criteria.

Answer (score 0):

I have tested the below in MS Access 2007, and it goes to the 3rd record in the recordset.
How many records are in your recordset?  Have you stepped through your code using F8?  where does it hang at when you are stepping through?
Additionally, you can do ALT+Pause Break to break out of the code.  Sometimes (because MS Access is not multi-threaded) it may take an inordinate amount of time for the break to be processed.

```
...
With rst
    .FindFirst ("field1 = 'xyz' and qty1 = 3")
End With
....
```

So, to answer your question, Yes, it can be done, and the below example you provided should work:

```
something.FindFirst ("Ref='XYZ' AND CustID=234")
```

Additionally, I believe that placing an index on a recordset is only useful when using the SEEK method.

*EDIT -- OP has now posted source code*

Try the below code instead.  I am assigning the rsImport fields to variables, and on the date, pre-formatting so it doesn't have to do a conversion during a compare.  Step through the code to see if there is any improvement in performace.  I don't have the ability to test this code right now, so the hash's around the date variables may need to be tweaked a little bit, and s_RefID may not be a string, so that data type may need to be adjusted as well.

The other change I made was to reset the position of rssql to the first record after each search.

```
dim rsImport as DAO.recordset, rsSQL as DAO.recordset
dim s_RefID as STRING
dim d_RefDate as date
set rsimport=CurrentDB().OpenRecordset("SELECT * from tblImport",dbopenSnapshot)
 rsimport.movelast
 rsimport.movefirst
set rsSQL=CurrentDB().OpenRecordset("SELECT * from tblRecords",dbOpenDynaset, dbSeeChanges)
 rsSQL.movelast
 rssql.movefirst

s_RefID = rsImport!RefID
d_RefDate = #format(rsimport!CustDate,"m-d-yy")#
do while rsimport.eof=false
   rssql.findfirst "[RefID]='" & s_RefID & "' AND [RefDate]=#" & d_RefDate & "#"
   if rssql.nomatch=true then
       debug.print "NOT FOUND - Add..."
   else
       debug.print "FOUND - Update..."
   endif
   rsimport.movenext
   rssql.movefirst

   s_RefID = rsImport!RefID
   d_RefDate = #format(rsimport!CustDate,"m-d-yy")#
loop
```

Comment: Hi Texas.  I know that it works in Access/Access, as that how I started, but when I migrated to Access/SQL Server is when I started having problems.  I Pause/Breaked and stepped through and it takes ages on the rs.findfirst statement.  If indexes on the server only assist if using seek, is there anyway I can optimise when using findfirst, or should I look at using seek.  I have circa 1000 records in a first recordset, each record in this is then looked for in 5000 records in the second recordset so it can then be added/updated.

Comment: I'm not talking about the database itself, but rather the code.  Keep the indexes in the SQL Server.  How are you creating the recordset in Access from SQL server?  Post the code as part of your question.